# Emberjs inside of get computed making request to backend multiple times cause infinite loop

Tags: ember.js

I have a table basically in every row i have get function that makes a backend request with store service. But somehow when there is one row it works expect, but when there is multiple rows it always try to recalculate get function which makes sending infinite request to backend. I am using `glimmer component`

I cannot use model relation on ember side at this point, there is deep chain on backend side. Thats why i am making backend request.

```
get <function_name>() {
  return this.store.query('<desired_model_name>', { <dependent1_id>: <dependent1_id_from_args>, <dependent2_id>: <dependent2_id_from_args> });
}
```

I fixed this problem with using constructor. But do you have any idea why this get function re-calculate all the time? `Dependent_ids` are constant.

Weird thing is when results are `[]` empty array it does not re calculate every time. Even the query results are same it still try to recalculate every time and making infinite request to backend.

Comment: what version of `ember-source` are you using?

Comment: My ember-source version is 3.28

Comment: excellent! that is compatible with nearly all the features in v4 (via polyfills or other)

Answer (score 1):

> But do you have any idea why this get function re-calculate all the time?

When something like this happens, it's because you're reading `@tracked` data that is changed later (maybe when the query finishes).

because `get`ters are re-ran every access, you'll want to throw `@cached` on top of it,

```js
// cached is available in ember-source 4.1+
// or as early as 3.13 via polyfill:
// https://github.com/ember-polyfills/ember-cached-decorator-polyfill
import { cached } from '@glimmer/tracking';
// ...

@cached
get <function_name>() {
  return this.store.query(/* ... */);
}
```

this ensures a stable object reference on the getter that the body of the getter only re-evaluates if tracked data accessed within the getter is changed.

> Weird thing is when results are [] empty array it does not re calculate every time. Even the query results are same it still try to recalculate every time and making infinite request to backend.

Given this observation, it's possible that when `query` finishes, that it's changing tracked data that it, itself is consuming during initial render -- in which case, you'd still have an infinite loop, even with `@cached` (because tracked-data is changing that was accessed during render).

To get around that is fairly hard *in a getter*.
Using a constructor is an ok solution for getting your initial data, but it means you opt out of reactive updates with your query (if you need those, like if the query changes or anything).

---

If you're using ember-source 3.25+ and you're wanting something a little easier to work with, maybe [ember-data-resourecs](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources) suits your needs

the above code would be:

```js
import { query } from 'ember-data-resources';
// ...
// in the class body
data = query(this, 'model name', () => ({ query stuff }));
```

[docs here](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/ember-data-resources#query)

This builds off some primitives from [ember-resources](https://github.com/nullvoxpopuli/ember-resources) which implement the Resource pattern, which will be making a strong appearance in the next edition of Ember.

Comment: Thanks for you input actually, I was wondering reason! It is really good explanation for me :)